Firebase Security Rules: Unable to Read Custom Token Claims in request.auth.token
I am having trouble with reading Firebase custom token in my security rules; it was working fine previously, but idk why now, I am unable to read tokens and due to this, all of my security rules are not being false.
SECURITY RULES (sample):
match /TUTORS/{docID} {
  allow read: if isSignedIn() && isTutor();
}

Now I always get false from isTutor function:
function isTutor() {
  return request.auth.token.role == "tutor";
}

I am setting custom token like this using Firebase Admin SDK using this same service account. I am doing other operations as well which are successful.
const additionalClaims = {
    role: "tutor",
};
const auth = admin.auth();

try {
       await auth.setCustomUserClaims(uid, additionalClaims);

    const customToken = await auth.createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims);
    return {
        type: "success",
        token: customToken,
    };
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating custom token:", error);
    return {
        type: "error",
        token: null,
    };
}

I am getting the token as well like this:
"ey**"
This was working fine a few days back but i can't figure out the reason why it is not working now. If i remove the roles checking func from security rules, the rules start to work, so i am pretty sure that issue lies in custom tokens.
also I did this:
const user = await admin.auth().getUser(uid);
console.log('User custom claims:', user.customClaims);

and got:
User custom claims:
{role: "tutor"}


Verified custom claims are set (getUser(uid) shows { role: "tutor" }).
Refreshed the ID token on the client using user.getIdToken(true).
Simulated requests in Firestore Security Rules Simulator, but request.auth.token does not include role .

Edit :
Here's how I'm refreshing and logging the custom token
    const idToken = await user.getIdToken(true);
    const decodedToken = await user.getIdTokenResult();
    console.log("Decoded Token:", decodedToken);
    console.log("role is : ", decodedToken.claims.role);


Moreover, it works just fine on the client without "refreshing" and
I can access the role, The issue is just that the custom claim is not being included in the request to the database

You say in step 2 you "Refreshed the ID token on the client using user.getIdToken(true)." Can you show the code that does this, and can you in that code print the ID token and share it here (there's no security risk from doing this, and it'll allow us to decode/inspect the token in a tool like jwt.io to see if the custom claim is present)?

@FrankvanPuffelen edited the question, can access the role just fine on the client, the token does include it

Please log idToken in that last snippet and include its output. Also: keep in mind that it's best if you share a minimal-but-complete code sample, rather than just snippets. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example for more on this.
